Cannot Connect to MqttNet Server running on Android/MAUI Blazor Project
I have created a Server Android Blazor MAUI project and bound and started it as a foreground service.
I cannot connect to server from a pc client. I tested with other andorid MQTT broker apps and can connect but not with my project app. So I am sure my tablet is accessible from the outside.
You can check my codes:
https://github.com/ozersenol/Athlantys.MQTT
I tried both local IP and device IP, but still cannot connect it.
public async Task StartServer()
{
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

    var result = new List<IPAddress>();
    try
    {
        var upAndNotLoopbackNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback 
                && n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);

        foreach (var networkInterface in upAndNotLoopbackNetworkInterfaces)
        {
            var iPInterfaceProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

            var unicastIpAddressInformation = iPInterfaceProperties.UnicastAddresses
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            if (unicastIpAddressInformation == null)
                continue;

            result.Add(unicastIpAddressInformation.Address);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unable to find IP: {ex.Message}");
    }

    // if (result.Count() > 0)
    // {
    //     ipAddress = result.FirstOrDefault();
    // }

    Console.Write("IP ADRESS: ");
    Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);

    var options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
        .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883)
        .WithDefaultEndpointBoundIPAddress(ipAddress)
        .WithDefaultEndpointBoundIPV6Address(IPAddress.None)
        .WithPersistentSessions()
        .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883)
        .WithKeepAlive()
        .WithoutEncryptedEndpoint()
        .Build();

    var server = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer(options);
    try
    {
        await server.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("MQTT SERVER STARTED..............");

        await Task.CompletedTask;
        // await server.StopAsync();
        // Console.WriteLine("MQTT SERVER STOPPED..............");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}


Is it possible, that your application exits immediatly after calling this method? I don't know Blazor MAUI, but I saw in your github, that _mqttService.StartServer(); is not awaited. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Thanks but unfortunately it did not solve the problem @JeanotZubler. I guess there mus be something else as trick...
